# How to find the files changed in one branch when another has been merged into it (ignoring changes from the merged branch)?

Tags: git

I have been working on a feature with a few colleagues on a branch "b1", this work has gone on over a few months and somebody decided to merge in the changes from master to try and reduce the possibility of merge conflicts further down the line.

```
|
|\  
| \
|  \   (branch point)
|   |
|   |
|   |
|___|    (merge)
|   |
|   |
|   |    (current state)
    (b1)
```

Work had been ongoing on master before it was merged into b1. I would like to know what files have been changed ONLY in b1, ignoring all of the commits which are now in the history of b1 which were brought in by merging master in.

I have tried using various git log options to do so such as the --no-merges option, which seems to only ignore the actual merge commits.

I have also tried to simply find the files changed by each of us in the history using a command like so:

```
git log --no-merges --author="Jeff" --name-only --pretty=format:"" <branch_point>..HEAD
```

However, as we have all done work which was in master at the time of merge, it is not clear what has been changed in which branch.

Is there a nice, clean way to find out the files changed **only** in b1?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there are no conflicts, `git diff master...b1` (i.e. triple dot).

That's not so well defined in a common case. I guess one of the meaningful ways it to merge master into b1 again and then `diff` the merge result with the master. In this case it will show meaningful difference with all conflicts/inconsistencies solved by the merge.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for your help. It seems, however that it works with a double dot but not with a triple. I assume this is because the common ancestor is now HEAD though. Thanks again :)